# How to fix this error Cannot read property 'attribut_id' of undefined

Tags: angular

At me at loading of page there is such error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribut_id' of undefined
>
> at eval (values.component.ts:132)
>
> at Array.filter () at
>   SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (values.component.ts:132)
>
> at
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
>
> at SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:190)
>
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
>    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>
> at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)

But the error does not always appear, and from time to time. And when error are not present the data is displayed completely, and if the error appeared then the data will not be displayed.

```
  id: number;
  routeId: any;
  returnUrl: string;
  sprTypeEvents: Array<SprTypeEvent>;
  eventAttributes: Array<EventAttribute>;

  filteredEventAttributes =[];
  _sprTypeEvent: SprTypeEvent;

  public errorMsg;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService, 
    private servSprTypeEvent: SprTypeEventService,
    private servEventAttribute: EventAttributeService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.sprTypeEvents = new Array<SprTypeEvent>();
  }

  @Input() sprTypeEvent: SprTypeEvent;

  @Input('typeEvent') set typeEvent (value: SprTypeEvent) {
    this._sprTypeEvent = value;
    if(this._sprTypeEvent) {
        this.loadEventAttributes();  
    }
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/layout/events';
    this.routeId = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
      }
    )
    let sprTypeEventRequest = this.route.params.flatMap(
      (params: Params) => this.servSprTypeEvent.getSprTypeEvent(+params['id'])
    );

    sprTypeEventRequest.subscribe(
      response => this.sprTypeEvent = response.json(),  
      error => this.errorMsg = error
    );

  }

  private loadEventAttributes() {
    this.servEventAttribute.getEventAttributes().subscribe(
      eventAttribute => {
        this.eventAttributes = eventAttribute;
        this.filteredEventAttributes = this.eventAttributes.filter(
          (eventAttribute) => eventAttribute.spr_typeevents_id == this._sprTypeEvent.typeevent_id
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

How it can be fixed?

Comment: Check if `@Input() attribute: Attribute;` is correctly set in your component

Comment: @mrkernelpanic "Is it correctly established" in the Sense?

Comment: can you show what is in Attribute ..?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the exception is because the input has not been filled at the time of the `ngOnInit` method.

You can use getters/setters in order to be "notified" whenever your input `attribute` changed:

```
_attribute: Attribute

@Input('attribute')
set attribute (value: Attribute) {
    this._attribute = value;
    if(this._attribute) {
        this.loadValues();  
    }
}
```

Of course, in your `loadValues` method, you should use `this._attribute` then.

Comment: It did not help me

Comment: That does not help me help you. How did it not help you? Did anything change? How does the problem present itself after the changes?

Comment: Absolutely nothing has changed

Comment: Are you still executing `loadValues` in the `ngOnInit` method? If so: don't do that

Comment: But at me so simply the information has ceased to be displayed

Comment: Are you still getting the original error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribut_id' of undefined`?

Comment: The error has disappeared, and the data is not displayed at all.

Comment: I displayed in the component.ts issue with corrections

Comment: put a breakpoint into the setter. Does it get called and is there any data at some point?

Comment: To tell the truth not absolutely understood about what control point there is a speech, it is not caused (after I removed from ngOnInit()) and the data therefore is not present

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur if value of attribute is not setted in the component so to avoid the error  you can instantiate the value of attribute like this

```
@Input() attribute=new Attribute();
```

but you need to set the make sure the value for attribute is setted so all the data can be displayed

Comment: The error  disappeared, but the data ceases to be displayed from time to time

Comment: yes that is because the value of attribute is not setted from the other component you are passing it. Can you share how you pass attribute value from the other component ?